# Correct way to point one variable on another in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want the variable `attachedImagesListKey` to point on different variables depending on the case. I implemented it this way.

```
var attachedImagesListKey = event.toFront
          ? frontAttachedImagesListKey
          : backAttachedImagesListKey;
```

But when I want to do some operations with `attachedImagesListKey`, such as

```
attachedImagesListKey.currentState
          .insertItem(item);
```

The exception is thrown

```
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'insertItem' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: insertItem(0)
```

Am I doing something wrong and what's the best way to implement this?

Comment: It seems that `currentState` of `attachedImagesListKey` is null, which means whichever key you assigned to it also has a null `currentState`. This could be because you haven't assigned that key to a widget or because you tried to reference the state before the linked widget was built. Without seeing more code or an explanation of what you're trying to do, it's uncertain which is the case here.

Comment: @Abion47 
That's how the most important code looks like. It won't work because there is no structure, but maybe it will be enough to see the problem.
https://gist.github.com/sergiyvergun/221653ff5183532abac58f6045010071
I print text every time the widget is built, and it does all the time, so the state should also be assigned.  But the same error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely in how you are (micro)managing your keys. First, you declare your specialized keys as global variables (a practice which I wish to discourage as much as possible):

```dart
GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> frontAttachedImagesListKey =
    GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();
GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> backAttachedImagesListKey =
    GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();
```

Then in your widget class, you declare your general key:

```dart
class _AttachedImagesState extends State<AttachedImages> {
  ...

  var animatedListKey;

  ...
}
```

...and then you initialize it in the `initState` method:

```dart
class _AttachedImagesState extends State<AttachedImages> {
  ...

  @override
  void initState() {
    ...
    animatedListKey =
        widget.isFront ? frontAttachedImagesListKey : backAttachedImagesListKey;
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

Here we run into the first part of the problem. You are declaring two keys, but are only using one of them in your widget. The other one becomes orphaned.

The second part of the problem is in your bloc code:

```dart
class NewImageBloc extends Bloc<NewImageEvent, NewImageState> {
  ...
  Stream<NewImageState> _mapPickImageEventToState(PickImage event) async* {
      ...

      var attachedImagesListKey = event.toFront
          ? frontAttachedImagesListKey
          : backAttachedImagesListKey;

      ...

      attachedImagesListKey.currentState.insertItem(imagesPaths.length);

      ...
   }
  ...
}
```

Remember how one of the keys was orphaned? Depending on the value of `event.toFront`, you are potentially selecting this key for your later processes. The orphaned key will, of course, have null as its `currentState`.

The real issue is that the way you are using your keys is very prone to these kinds of mix-ups and errors. Instead of declaring your keys as global variables, you should be declaring them locally. (Also, you shouldn't be using `GlobalKey` unless for some reason you want this widget to be globally accessible.) You can then pass them to the bloc's constructor or provide them in some other manner.

Alternatively, if you *do* want to have these widgets be globally accessible, then in order to reconcile the orphaned key you must maintain both corresponding widgets. Then you hide one or the other based on the value of `isFront`.

It's also worth noting that depending on what you are actually trying to do here, you should consider refactoring your code to eliminate the need to rely on keys at all. If all you're trying to do is flip the state of a widget to be "front" or "back", that can be done just as easily (and more simply) using a callback or event bus.

(From here it is an architectural decision, which is a broad and opinionated topic, and I don't understand your code or your app architecture as well as you do. You're going to have to make your own decisions from this point on on how to proceed.)

Comment: I use global key to handle AnimatedList, just as it was shown in this short video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZtfItHwFlZ8 . So better solution will be just to pass animatedList's state directly to bloc instead of using global key? Or maybe there is another type of key which I can use to handle state? 
Thank you for your response! It's really helpful.